# Multiple nested echo statements piped to command kernel limitation

Tags: linux, bash, centos, iptables

I've got a straight forward bash script generated with fwbuilder that nests several echo statements and pipes them through to iptables-restore.
We compile this way instead of just having multiple "iptables -A xxx" lines since it compiles and deploys much quicker and it also doesn't drop existing connections.

The problem is we seem to have hit the limit of allowed multiple redirects (~23'850 lines don't work, ~23'600 lines do).
Run it on kernel 2.6.18 (CentOS 5.x) and it breaks, run it on 2.6.32 (6.x) and it works like a charm.

Script essentially looks like this, comes out as just one long line piped to the command:

> (echo "1"; echo "2"; echo "3"; ... ; echo "25000") | /do/anything

So I guess the question is, is there an easy way to increase this limit without recompiling the kernel? I'd imagine it's some sort of stdin character limitation of piping. Or do I have to do an OS upgrade?

edit: Oh and would also like to add that when running on the older kernel, no errors are shown, but a segfault shows in dmesg.

Comment: Do you have to do the script this way? Why not a here-doc?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by here-doc? Never used anything like that...Ok nvm I see another user defined it. I think that won't work due to how the fwbuilder auto-generates the script.

Comment: Not another user, the same user. :)

Comment: Ah. Well, we managed to circumvent this by just optimizing our rules a bit thus lessening the string we pipe through, so now it's running again. It was decided to just do an OS upgrade since there are other smaller bugs that warrant an upgrade anyway. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're not observing the problem on 2.6.32 and observing it on 2.6.18 is that starting with kernel 2.6.23 the `ARG_MAX` limitation has been removed.  [This](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b6a2fea39318e43fee84fa7b0b90d68bed92d2ba) is the commit for the change.

In order to find some ways to circumvent the limit, see [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Comment: Will look into this, sounds like it may help

Comment: How is ARG_MAX related to this? He's piping to stdin, not substituting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a here-doc instead?

```
cat <<EOF | /do/anything
1
2
3
...
25000
EOF
```

Comment: Don't think this will work because of how fwbuilder auto-generates a script each time, it could be cumbersome to do this manually each time. Plus it increase the chance of user error. Thanks for the suggestion though :).